# Getting 404 when accessing static file from ktor server

Tags: kotlin, server, backend, ktor, static-files

My files are stored under `uploads` folder next to my fat jar server and files are getting saved there properly but while accessing these files over a cloud server `http://{IP_ADDRESS}:8085/uploads/image1.png`, I'm getting 404.
This works perfectly fine on my localhost.

*//Directory structure*

```
root@localhost:~/ktor# ls
build my-server.jar  uploads
```

*//Backend code*

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {

    routing {
        staticRoutes()
    }
}


fun Route.staticRoutes() {
    val projectRoot = File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
    staticFiles("/uploads/", File("${projectRoot}\\uploads"))
}
```

Not sure what am I missing, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the backslash path delimiter (`"${projectRoot}\\uploads"`). The following code works as expected:

```
fun Route.staticRoutes() {
    val projectRoot = File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
    staticFiles("/uploads", projectRoot.resolve("uploads"))
}
```